# Bigquery join 2 tables with id concated from 4 columns and create a new table dynamically

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables in Bigquery from two different data sources, lets say x and y. I want to join these two tables on os_name, tracker_name, date, country  columns. For that i am using concat function and joining like this:

```
  full outer join x on concat(x.date,x.os_name,x.tracker_name, x.country) = concat(y.date,y.os_name,y.tracker_name,y.country_code)
```

as a query result common columns also gets duplicated. like in the result there is os_name and os_name_1, country_code, country_code_1 etc. columns. I don't want that. Final columns should be as in the example below in Final Table Schema.

I want to return all records from both sides. For example if there is no match in table y
y_install, and y_purcase will be 0, and vice versa.

X TABLE SCHEMA:

- os_name,
- tracker_name,
- date ,
- country
- install
- purchase

Y TABLE SCHEMA:

- os_name,
- tracker_name,
- date,
- country,
- y_install,
- y_purchase

Final Table Schema required:

- os_name,
- tracker_name,
- date ,
- country
- install
- purchase,
- y_install,
- y_purchase

I am going to schedule the query and write results to destination table at given interval.

Can you help me out with this query.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the final table, I don't understand whether you want to return first NON NULL result or whether you want to have e.g. an array which will contain both results from both tables in case both tables a valid value. In my sample table, do you want row 1,2 (actually the same thing) or 3?

| row_number | x_install | y_install | final_table_install |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 50 | 23 |
| 2 | NULL | 50 | 50 |
| 3 | 23 | 50 | [23,50] |

Answer (score 0):

It comes out that What I wanted to use was union all. First, I added the non-common columns to the two tables so that the schemas of the two tables are equal. So I was able to vertically merge tables using union all. Thanks for trying to help out anyway.

Comment: You can also edit your question and add the addendum to it